# Exoplayer highlighted element on controller

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a strange bug with a exoplayer as you can see here [image: on this picture]
Sometimes, only on player initialisation, one button is highlighted.
When bar controller disapear and coming back, there are no problem.

I don't know where I can start to looking for.
Is anybody have any idea ?

For the moment, I think it's a problem of selected view, but may i'm wrong...

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your controller or default exoplayer's controller? If this is your own controller then your play/pause button gets focus. You should remove focus from that button.

Comment: I started from default exo_playback_control_view and I have added some button and textview. How can I check focus on button ?

Comment: try this tags in root layout
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: It works partially, blue overlay disapear well, but my hard keyboard entry not work. Can I force focus on main activity ?

Comment: Instead of giving above tags in the root layout you can add `android:focusable="false"` this line in play/pause button which restict the view to get focus. In above comment I told to use  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" line which restrict the descendant to get the focus.

Comment: Understood, I've tried to set like this, just to try :
<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
            android:focusable="false" />
Blue overlay is still here.
I'v forget to say, that happened just after using hardKeyboad. I have an "onKeyUp" method used elsewhere.

Comment: It's OK, it works now, I have an other little bug, but the correct answer was  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  on root layout, thanks you very much @meet Patel